# Javascript Array, adding a array in correct place

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I have an array:

```
a = new Array(1,3,6,8,10,12);
b = 7;
```

Using Javascript/JQuery how can I insert the value 7 (or another number) into the array so it appears sequentially in the array.

The array would then be:

```
b = new Array(1,3,6,7,8,10,12);
```

Thanks

Comment: You should show you work. What did you try?

Comment: b.sort((a,b)=>a-b)